# Local Vim, local filesystem and SSH client with SSH-Agent in Chromebook?

Tags: vim, ssh, filesystems, ssh-agent, chromebook

I read somewhere that this is possible after enabling the developer switch but cannot find how to access it. A thread [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4083175) explains something about the javascript plugin containing the ssh tool but missing the local version discussion. So how can I have local fs, local Vim and ssh client in Chromebook? With SSH client, I also. want the key authentication aka ssh-agent.

**How can I get this kind of Chromebook less resilient for developing without internet? Development requires local tools such as Vim, local FS and SSH-Client with SSH-Agent.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the developer switch ON. The switch is virtualized above October/November 2012 Samsung models at least. Instructions [here](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-series-5-chromebook).

**Instructions to get Bash, Vim, Ssh-agent etc tools after having the Developer switch ON**

> You need to open the Crosh and then type-and-press-enter like `"shell ENTER"` or see also `"help ENTER"`. So this way get a full-blown bash with ssh-agent and Vim:
>
> > CTRL+ALT T
> >
> > crosh> shell
> >
> > chrosos@localhost / $ echo $SHELL
> >
> > /bin/bash
> >
> > chrosos@localhost / $ vim

**Perhaps related**

1. Some discussion about getting Chromebook in use https://plus.google.com/109993695638569781190/posts/BHo38NLkMz4
2. the Secure Shell app has some problems with certain Chromebooks such as Samsung October 2012, hanging up to NaCL
3. [Programming on samsung chromebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299685/programming-on-samsung-chromebook)

*P.s. And if you want to switch to your favorite keyboard layout such as Dvorak, you can find it in chrome://settings/languages.*