# How do I get python on my google chromebook?

Tags: python, chromebook

I am new to programming. I can't figure out how to download Python onto my Chromebook. I found this link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python/nodpmmidbgeganfponihbgmfcoiibffi

But there's no option to download.

Edit: I python to open by putting my chromebook in developer mode, but I can't figure out how to get to python shell.

Comment: What happens when you click the “add to desktop” button?

Comment: I can't find any "add to desktop" button

Comment: Huh weird that’s what I see on mobile, figured it would be somewhere on desktop as well

Comment: You probably need to enter developer mode in order to install python on a chromebook (how to do that depends on the exact type of chromebook you are using so Google it). However, be aware that making that sort of modification to your chromebook will probably void any warranty you might have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programming on samsung chromebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299685/programming-on-samsung-chromebook)

Answer (score 2):

I think that will be ok.
If you add that ap to your Chromebook, you can run on its python.

In any case:
In oder to open the shell you have to press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.

Or maybe you'll find that useful; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7Y8b2S3nEA